# How can I force VS2015 to always load symbols when debugging an ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to debug a combination of an ASP.NET MVC 5.2 application along with a console app (that is communicating to the ASP application), so while working on it I'm regularly making changes to the console app without modifying the web app. I am trying to have both set as the (multiple) startup projects, however this problem happens when I just have the web app set as the (single) startup project.

#### Problem

When I make a modification to the ASP.NET code (or dependencies) and then Start Debugging (F5), it recompiles, launches my browser, and everything is good.

If I stop debugging, then immediately start again (without making any changes), it doesn't attach the debugger. On a breakpoint, I get the error "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

[image]

#### Other observations

I did notice after I press Stop in VisualStudio, iisexpress stays running with web app still working.

Interestingly, when I go to "Attach to process" after I've started debugging (but while it doesn't have symbols loaded), `iisexpress.exe` is grayed out, indicating it's already attached.

If I use "Attach to process" to attach to the running `iisexpress.exe` while debugging is not started (but no other code changes or recompilations have been done), it also doesn't load symbols.

---

How can I get it to load symbols correctly? This could include forcing iisexpress to stop when I stop debugging, or forcing the web application to *always* recompile even if there are no code changes.

Comment: I did find a workaround, which is to [touch the web.config in a post-build event and force IISExpress to restart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590963/can-visual-studio-restart-iis-express-on-new-debugging-session). I don't really understand why this works -- it's still the same source code, binaries and pdb files -- while simply attaching VS to the existing process doesn't. Surely there is a better way than this, though?

Comment: Another workaround: clean your solution between debugging sessions.

Comment: I had to close both instances of VS2013 and VS2015.  Open VS2015 and not VS2013.