# IIS Rewrite module web.config rewrite rule update not considered

Tags: asp.net, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to change a redirection in my web project. However, when I change the rewrite rule in my web.config file the update is not considered and I still got the old url destination. I tried cleaning the project, but in vain. I think that there's somewhere a version cached of my web.config and I can't figure out how to find it and override it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the *application pool* in which you are running your ASP.Net application. Simply updating the web.config on the server won't work, as you've already noticed.

Comment: I am using IIS Express on local, do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about IIS Express. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590963/can-visual-studio-restart-iis-express-on-new-debugging-session , this may help

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but relevant.
What solved this problem for me was clearing cache in the web browser

Answer (score 0):

The reason why IIS does not update your ruling is that there is an error in web.config. I've had the same issue, clearing the mistake in web.config did the trick