# Force a new start of "Cassini" when I start debugging a new instance of my web application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In our ASP.NET application we perform some initializations upon the Application Start event.

When the application is started in visual Studio 2010 with 'Debug->Start new instance' the ASP.NET Development server does not start new, and my Application's Start event is not fired.

My workaround is to manually stop the development server - is there a setting to force this automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically stop/restart ASP.NET Development Server on Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886692/automatically-stop-restart-asp-net-development-server-on-build)

Comment: Thanks Patrick - this seems indeed to be a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think setting `Project properties > Web > Enable Edit and Continue` forces Cassini to restart when debugging is started.