# Visual Studio 2010 nasty caching Cassini? Must manually stop service

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've spent waaaay too much time trying to figure this out. I'm running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 **in a VMware Fusion virtual**.

When I debug my website project, Cassini (aka ASP.NET Web Development Server) starts and the site shows in my default browser (IE). I stop the debugger, make some tweaks to my C# code, and start the debugger again. The website starts up in IE and the site displays, but its using the code base from when I initially debugged NOT including any tweaks in code between the initial debug/build and subsequent debugs/builds.

The only way I can get code changes to build and run in the browser properly is if I manually stop the ASP.Net Web Development Server from the tray and then run debug.

Has anyone encountered this? Not sure if its caused by VS2010 or the environment being a virtual on a Mac.

Manually stopping Cassini after every debug is really starting to suck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I had mapped my Visual Studio 2010 folders to a VMware Fusion share in order to make my .NET projects accessible from Mac world (for copying graphics files into the projects, etc.). Evidently there was some type of permission issue or something that did not result in any sort of alert that was causing the problem.

I remapped all VS folders (Project, Website, etc.) into the standard Documents folder of my user instance and everything began working as expected.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will have a more pleasant experience with [IIS 7.5 Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) as a replacement for Cassini.
From that page:

> IIS Express is a lightweight,
>   self-contained version of IIS
>   optimized for developers. IIS Express
>   makes it easy to use the most current
>   version of IIS to develop and test
>   websites. It has all the core
>   capabilities of IIS 7 as well as
>   additional features designed to ease
>   -- website development including:
>   -- It doesn't run as a service or
>      require administrator user rights to
>      perform most tasks.
>   -- IIS Express works well with ASP.NET and PHP applications.
>       -- Multiple users of IIS Express can work independently on the same
>   computer.

Here's an [article](http://%20%20%20%20Skip%20to%20Comments%20%20%20%20%20Add%20a%20Comment%20%20Debug%20Your%20.NET%20Web%20Project%20With%20IIS%20Express%20%5BTips%20&%20Tricks%5D) to help you get started.

Comment: I have tried using IIS Express to see if my issue was tied to Cassini but same effect. Code changes not reflected even after stop/start unless I manually close the site in IIS Express.

Comment: How frustrating! Did you check out [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886692/automatically-stop-restart-asp-net-development-server-on-build)?

Answer (score 1):

Check if Visual Studio is set to recompile the projects when there are changes.

Check that `Tools > Options > Projects and solutions > Build and run > On run, when projects are out of date` is set to `Always build`.

Comment: Yes, VS is set to that. No dice.